# How to add multiple views on button click using react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, onclick, native-base

I am new to react native and I would like to add a new view each time the plus button is pressed I have tried a few things myself but I haven't been successful so far.
My end goal is to add a input fields for passenger details each time the user hits the plus button something similar tothe google trips app.
Following is the code that I have been trying to execute:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Container, Header, Title, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon, Text, Form, Item, Input,
    Label, Grid, Col, Toast
} from 'native-base';

export default class AddBus extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            basic: true,
            passengerListView: [],
            info: "",
            viewSection: false
        };
    }

    renderBottomComponent() {
        if (this.state.viewSection) {

            for (count = 0; count <= 5; count++) {

                return (
                    <Content>
                        <Grid>
                            <Col style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                <Item floatingLabel>
                                    <Icon name="ios-person" />
                                    <Label>Passenger</Label>
                                    <Input />
                                </Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col style={{ flex: 0 }}>
                                <Button transparent >
                                    <Icon name="close" />
                                </Button>
                            </Col>
                        </Grid>

                        <Item floatingLabel>
                            <Label>Seat</Label>
                            <Input />
                        </Item>

                        <Item floatingLabel last>
                            <Label>Confirmation number </Label>
                            <Input />
                        </Item>
                    </Content>
                )

            }

        }
    }

    render() {
        const { passengerListView } = this.state;

        return (
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                            <Icon name="arrow-back" />
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Title>Add bus</Title>
                    </Body>
                    <Right>
                        <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                            <Icon name="ios-folder" />
                        </Button>
                    </Right>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <Form>
                        <Item floatingLabel>
                            <Label>Where from?</Label>
                            <Input />
                        </Item>
                        <Item floatingLabel >
                            <Label>Where to?</Label>
                            <Input />
                        </Item>
                        <Item floatingLabel>
                            <Icon name="calendar" />
                            <Label>Departure date</Label>
                            <Input />
                        </Item>
                        <Item floatingLabel>
                            <Icon name="ios-calendar" />
                            <Label>Arrival date</Label>
                            <Input />
                        </Item>
                        <Grid>
                            <Col style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                <Item floatingLabel>
                                    <Icon name="ios-person" />
                                    <Label>Passenger</Label>
                                    <Input />
                                </Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col style={{ flex: 0 }}>
                                <Button transparent onPress={() => this.setState({ viewSection: true })} >
                                    <Icon name="add" />
                                </Button>
                            </Col>
                        </Grid>

                        <Item floatingLabel>
                            <Label>Seat</Label>
                            <Input />
                        </Item>

                        <Item floatingLabel last>
                            <Label>Confirmation number </Label>
                            <Input />
                        </Item>

                        {this.renderBottomComponent()}

                    </Form>

                </Content>

            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45477583/how-to-add-more-component-dynamically-react-native